# Working with inappbrowser and latest cordova 5.4.x version

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, inappbrowser

I have my plugin (`inappbrowser`) and `cordova` installed. I also have used the `window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;` command to target `window.open` as documented in d newer version in my html file but only my web view works and inapp browser does not.

Also netbeans writes out cordova as not declared as global variable when used in the statement

`window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;`

Bringing error indication in d line

Need full tutorial to make inappbrowser work in the latest cordova.

my index.html is as follow

this my index.html

```
         <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Primrose AVR</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" >

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


        enter code here

       window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
        var iabRef = null;

        function iabLoadStart(event) {
            alert("Loading : " + event.type);
        }
        function iabLoadStop(event) {
            alert("loaded : " + event.type);
        }
        function iabLoadError(event) {
            alert("Error loading: " + event.type);
        }
        function iabClose(event) {
             alert(event.type);
             iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
             iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
             iabRef.removeEventListener('loaderror', iabLoadError);
             iabRef.removeEventListener('exit', iabClose);
        }

        function onDeviceReady() {



 // IN THE NEXT LINE WHERE cordova.InAppBrowser.open(); IS USED      //(NETBEANS PROMPT THAT CORDOVA IS NOT DECLARED AS A GLOBAL VARIABLE //VARIABLE),THEREFORE MAKING THE LINE IRRELEVANT AND WITH ERROR  


    cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://kyc.fcmb.com/PrimroseMobile/Security/SignInMobile.aspx/', '_self', 'location=yes'); 

             iabRef.addEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart); 
             iabRef.addEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop); 
             iabRef.addEventListener('loaderror', iabLoadError); 
             iabRef.addEventListener('exit', iabClose);
        }
        </script>
      </head>
      <body onload=" onDeviceReady()">


      </body>
        </html>
```

MY CONFIG.XML FILE

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" id="com.coolappz.PrimroseAvr" version="1.0.0">
    <name>Primrose Avr</name>
    <description>
        Application that works as an inappbrowser and webview.
    </description>
    <author email="b.akintoba@gmail.com" href="http://gmail.com">
        Badmus akintoba
    </author>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <preference name="permissions"                  value="none" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce"                value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView"     value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor"     value="#0177C6" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types"            value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview"              value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion"        value="14" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion"     value="22" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version"             value="cli-5.1.1" />

    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay"            value="10000" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen"                 value="screen" />

    <platform name="android">
        <icon src="www/logo.png" density="ldpi" />
        <icon src="www/logo.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="www/logo.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="www/logo.png" density="xhdpi" />
        <icon src="www/logo.png" density="xxhdpi" />
        <icon src="www/logo.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
        <splash src="www/al.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/ll.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="www/ml.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/al.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/al.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/al.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/ap.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/lp.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="www/mp.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/ap.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/ap.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/ap.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
    </platform>


    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1"/>
    <access origin="*"/>
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" />
</feature>
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
    <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
    </platform>
    </widget>
```

FINALLY I HAVE MY INAPPBROWSER PLUGIN INSTALLED BUT YET INAPPBROWSER IS NOT WORKING

PLS EXPERT HELP ME AM USING NETBEANS IDE TO DEVELOP THE ANDROID APP

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the InAppBrowser working, you would invoke it like this:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://stackoverflow.com, '_blank', iabOptions);
```

Note the use of uppercase in InAppBrowser.

Where:

- 'http://stackoverflow.com' is the URL you want to open in the InAppBrowser
- '_blank' specifies where you want to open it, use '_blank' for the InAppBrowser, '_system' for the device's default browser or '_self' for the Cordova webview (replacing your app's content)
- iabOptions is an optional string passing configuration information to the InAppBrowser, for example 'location=no' to turn off the address bar in the InAppBrowser

Proper usage of the IAB with documentation on the options can be found at the [NPM page for the IAB plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser).

Comment: I have read the documentation before .i appreciate ur suggestions but obviously i follow all the step in the documentation.if you are using the new cordova and inappbrowser and you have it working .let me know ..i am using netbean ide to develop

Comment: From what you have posted you appeared to be using incorrect case to refer to InAppBrowser for example.  Also, are you trying to use the IAB before the deviceready event has fired, and have you verified your plugin installation was successful?  To get more focussed assistance the community will need more context.

Comment: Simon ,i will post my project code to you shortly as soon as i connect to my pc

Comment: have edited my question check above to tell me where am making mistakes

Comment: It looks like you are doing this `window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;` before device ready event, so move that to your device ready handler, or just omit it and explicitly use cordova.InAppBrowser.open whenever you want to use the IAB.  You also don't want to call onDeviceReady on body load, just when the deviceready event fires.

Comment: @ simon ,i really appreciate your response .if you have work on a project like this just give me the working code u used ..because all suggestion you are giving are all have done earlier

Comment: Check out https://github.com/simonprickett/bartcordova/blob/master/app/www/js/app.js which is part of a complete, working demo project I did.

Comment: @ SIMON ,i don`t think you  are using NETBEANS to develop your application ..Because anytime i use the cordova statement in the netbeans coding area it prompt me that cordova is not declared as a global variable

Comment: I don't, but that shouldn't matter either.  cordova won't be declared until you are running the app on the device, because the cordova build process copies in the right cordova.js when building the app for Android, iOS or whatever other platform you are using.  You should have `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>` in your index.html and this will be unresolved in the www folder which is OK.